# Use git commands with another path rather than the actual working dir

Tags: git, repository

When using `git add .` uses the actual path where you're (incase is a git repo). How would I do for using `git add`, `git commit` and `git push' outside of the working dir? Like`git add /Users/zad0xsis/my-git-repo`.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: To clarify, you want to run the add command in a git repository outside of the current working directory?

Comment: exactly, really I want to run git add, git commit and git push on a directory outside the working directory

Answer (score 27):

I had success using the `git -C` option. Taken from the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt):

```
Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory.
```

It is very important that the `-C` option comes before actual command you want to execute:

```
Wrong:   git add . -C some-path
Correct: git -C some-path add .
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the git docs on my system (git 1.7.6) you can adjust the working directory (where the code resides) using `--work-tree` or `$GIT_WORK_TREE` and the repository directory (where the git objects reside) using `--git-dir` or `$GIT_DIR`. If that doesn't work you could use a wrapper script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /desired/path

git "$@"
```